# Is it possible to hide an id element in some browsers?

Tags: javascript, html, css

say that I have an id defined like this

```
<span id ="radiobuttonContainer"> Check to enable checkboxes: 
<input type="radio" name="cov-failed" value="cover" onclick="javascript:printoutCheckboxes('cover')">   
Coverage                
<input type="radio" name="cov-failed" value="failed" onclick="javascript:printoutCheckboxes('failed')"> 
Failed</span>
```

I dont want to show this "spanId" in browsers below I.E 9 Because this enables alot more vizualizing of data which IE < 8 don't can manage.  I know that you can have diffrent javascripts and css:es depending on browsers  like this

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]><script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="root/include/excanvas.min.js"></script><![endif]-->
```

And then chose display: 'none';

But I wonder if it really is nessecary to have 2 equal .css files containing exactly the same information besides this single row?

Can't I just do something like this?

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]>document.getElementById('radiobuttonContainer').style.display = 'none';<![endif]-->
```

Comment: why hide via js and not just by simple css which overrides `span#radiobuttonContainer { display:none; }`

Comment: @knittl yeah thats what I meant, I were to fast copying and pasting ;) How do you mean, where shall I post this, I know that you can do this via css, but I don't want to have 2 diffrent .css files. Can I do something like this??
<!--[if lte IE 8]>span#radiobuttonContainer { display:none; }<![endif]--> ? =)

Comment: What hides beneath the phrase "a lot more visualizing of data"? If it's a javascript feature that oldIE doesn't support, sniff for the feature, then hide the element. Note that the HTML will still be sent and parsed though, so hiding it may not be enough if it really causes oldIE to fail badly.

Comment: @Sean McMillan I'm using flot, and that radiobuttons enable you to plot more than 1 dataset at the Time, which I.E don't can manage =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can surely do something like this:

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]><script type="text/javascript">
   document.getElementById('radiobuttonContainer').style.display = 'none';
</script><![endif]-->
```

which is a merge of your examples by the way.

Comment: Yes, I voted up your comment in fact, but today 98% of browsers have javascript enabled, so, is it a real world issue in fact?

Comment: ah yes, i see the upvote now.  I suppose even if the radioButton is not hidden, the rest of the site won't work anyway, so it's one half dozen to the other at that point.  I always just prefer to use CSS first if I can.

Answer (score 4):

you should just be able to wrap the tag in a conditional comment.  alternately, since CSS included inline in the page takes precedence over included CSS, you wouldn't have to include a second style sheet, just a new definition specific for that case.  i.e.

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
<style type="text/css">
#radiobuttonContainer{
  display = 'none';
};
<![endif]-->
```

and have that come after your included CSS file.

Comment: Just wrote the exact same thing. Rarely am I able to answer anything on this site without somebody beating me to it! :)

Comment: Thank you for all alternative ways to solve the problem on, which one is the best? ;P

Comment: well, there's always the possibility that javascript is disabled, so a pure CSS approach is the most reliable.

Comment: @thescientist When I tried this but the radiobuttons were still shown when I'm putting that row at the exactly same spot as 

<!--[if lte IE 8]><script type="text/javascript">document.getElementById('radiobuttonContainer').style.display = 'none';</script><![endif]--> and that javascript worked. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: hmm, I would have put it in the < head >  (using JS or CSS implementations)

Comment: @thescientist How do you mean "using JS or CSS implementations", when I post the code exactly as written above in the <head> section, nothing is shown, the webpage is simply white. And when I put the line exactly where I put @Lex suggestion (That is at the bottom of the page just before the <script> tag where all the flot jquery is, nothing happens and the radiobuttons are still visible. =)

Answer (score 1):

if you use a tool like [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/), you can use it to determine the capabilities of the browser.

If there's a particular feature which isn't available in IE8, you can reference it in your stylesheet, and hide this element if the browser doesn't have that feature.

Lets say the feature is HTML5 canvas, all you'd need to do is the one line script to include the Modernizr Javascript in your page, and then you'd do something like this in your CSS:

```
.nocanvas .radiobuttonContainer {
    display:none;
}
```